# CSS to stick footer to window bottom and fill remaining space completely

Tags: css

I'm trying to stick a footer to the bottom of the browser window and fill the entire space above with a single div. After googling for more than an hour a found a couple of approaches to get the sticky footer. But I still fail to fill the remaining space.

This is my approach so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="background-color: #111111">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin: 0; padding:0;">
    <div style="color: white; background-color: #335544; width: 100%; align-self: stretch; margin: 0;">Content - This should fill all the space between top of the window down to the top of the footer.</div>
    <div style="color: white; background-color: #223344; width: 100%; position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 40px">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css function `calc` to find how much space needs to be filled.
This would be `calc(100% - 40px)` because `40px` is the height of your footer.

Take a look at this snippet

```html
<body style="background-color: #111111; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <div>
        <div style="color: white; background-color: #335544; width: 100%; height: calc(100vh - 40px);">Content - This should fill all the space between top of the window down to the top of the footer.</div>
        <div style="color: white; background-color: #223344; width: 100%; position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 40px">Footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
```